# Trying to filter out the students in a dataframe with a certain GPA using "R"

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhIMI.png)

Hello everyone, I'm not used to using StackOverflow in terms of asking questions, but I have used it to find solutions to problems I've had in the past. I'm currently taking an advanced programming class involving the use of the language "R". In problem 20 (shown in the picture above), I was tasked to filter out the students in df20 who have a GPA higher than 3.0 and put them into a new dataframe named "df20a" I was able to create the dataframe and reassign a value to a student shown in the example, but I am having trouble with the final steps. If anyone is able to help me with this solution and provide an explanation on how to achieve the result im looking for, It'd be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time & I hope you're having a wonderful and blessed day!

Comment: `df20a <- subsetdf20, gpa >3)`

Comment: You've saved me a butt load of time my friend! Thank you so much! @akrun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df20a <- df20[df20$gpa > 3 ,]
```

Explanation: df20a is equivalent to df20 where column *gpa* is greater than 3.